# I need to find out each student's top score from an array of their previous scores

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

First, an example of what I require from my function. An array of students is passed to the function, and the function returns an array with each student's top score as items.

```
getStudentTopScores([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Jacek",
    scores: [5, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ewa",
    scores: [2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 5]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zygmunt",
    scores: [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3]
  }
]) ➞ [5, 5, 4]
```

**Below is my working function. I need some help explaining exactly why it works.**

```
const getStudentTopScores=students=>
    students
    .map(student=>student.scores)
    .reduce((arr,scores)=>{
      const score = scores.length?Math.max(...scores):0;
      arr.push(score);
      return arr;
    },[]);
```

So, what is going on with my code?

1. An array of students is passed to the function **getStudentTopScores**
2. The **.map()** method is applied to the array:

   .map(student=>student.scores)
   I think that this is accessing the **scores** array stored inside students.
3. the **.reduce()** method is applied to each **score**. This takes each score and asks: **is this score the maximum score in the array?** If the answer is yes, then that value is stored in **score**, if the answer is no, then 0 is stored in **score**.

   4. the value stored in **score** is added to the accumulator (**arr**).
   5. That value is the particular students top score. 
      **What if there are multiple scores that are equal and maximum? Why aren't these all added to the accumulator, creating a value that is the sum of all the top scores for that individual?**

**The code only works with an empty array at the end. I've no idea why this is needed. Please explain this.**

Comment: Is the question about the `[]` in `reduce`? It's the [*intialValue*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters) of the accumulator:

Answer (score 0):

The map will return an array of array of scores,

reduce will loop through your array of array, for each item (an array of score) you select one element (the largest) and push it to the accumulator, therefore your accumulator can only have 1 value per element.

The empty array at the end of your reduce is the start value of the accumulator.

You can achieve the same result with this function
`s => s.map(c => Math.max(...c.scores))`

Answer (score 0):

For your questions mentioned in the 5th point:

If there are multiple scores that are equal and maximum, then the Math.max function just picks up the maximum value and hence these values are not added into the accumulator.

The empty array at the end is to pass an initial value to which the result of reduce will be pushed into.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce is a function that can loop every object in the array and can store the value from every iteration to the accumulator object, this is done by returning the value in an iteration.

Basic example would be

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce((accumulator, value) => {
  return accumulator + value
})
// outputs 10
```

Now look at this example

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce((accumulator, value) => {
  return accumulator + value
}, 20)
// now the output 30, because the initial value of accumulator is set to 20
// so 20 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 30
```

Now why you adding that [] works in your example.
Because the first argument of the reduce is object by default. 
Since in my example adding {} + 0 = 0. Javascript duh!

But in your example, you are pushing the value to the accumulator.

```
arr.push(highestValue)
```

Go ahead and open the console in your browser and type this

```
{}.push(5)

push is not a function
```

The same error which you would have got when running reduce function without [].
So I think by this time you would have figured it out, by passing [] you are explicitly setting accumulator value to array and now

```
arr.push()
```

works

And btw

```
Math.max
```

returns only single highest value even if you have multiple equal values.